# C++ - Using a variable without knowing what it is called

Tags: c++, c++11, plugins

I have a program that uses plug-ins. As I'm in development, these plug-ins are currently just .h and .cpp files that I add or remove from my project before re-compiling, but eventually they will be libraries.

Each plug-in contains lists of data in vectors, and I need to dynamically load data from the plug-ins without knowing which plug-ins are present. For instance:

```
// plugin1.h

extern vector<int> plugin1Data;

// plugin2.h

extern vector<int> plugin2Data;

// main.cpp

vector<vector<int>> pluginDataList;

int CountPlugins () {

    // Some function that counts how many plug-ins are present, got this bit covered ;)
}

int main() {

    int numPlugins = CountPlugins();

    for (int i = 0; i < numPlugins; i++) {

        vector<int> newPluginData = /***WAY TO ADD PLUGIN DATA!!!***/;

        pluginDataList.push_back(newPluginData);
    }
}
```

I already access the names of each plugin present during my CountPlugins() function, and have a list of names, so my first gut feeling was to use the name from each plugin to create a variable name like:

```
vector<string> pluginNames = /*filled by CountPlugins*/;

string pluginDataName = pluginNames.at(i) + "Data";

// Use pluginDataName to locate plugin1Data or plugin2Data
```

That's something I've done before in c# when I used to mess around with unity, but I've read a few stackoverflow posts clearly stating that it's not possible in c++. It's also a fairly messy solution in C# anyway as far as I remember.

If each plugin was a class instead of just a group of vectors, I could access the specific data doing something like plugin2.data... but then I still need to be able to reference the object stored within each plugin, and that'll mean that when I get round to compiling the plugins as libraries, I'll always have to link to class declaration and definition, which isn't ideal (though not out of the question if it'll give a nicer solution over all).

I'm all out of ideas after that, any help you can offer will be most welcome!

Thanks! Pete

Comment: why not create a base interface for you plugins and check which plugin to use at runtime thru the pure virtual functions?

Comment: Each plugin may "register" to your vector.

Comment: just read a bit about base classes. I can't figure out an approach that will solve my problem, could you expand on this?

Comment: If I understand your question, you're asking how to check if header file is *included*. Am I right?

Comment: No, for now I am manually including the header file. What I need to do right now is automatically detect the data that's declared in the header files and save it to vectors, as if I wasn't aware in advance which header files were there

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry, missed your comment, what do you mean by register? And which part of my plug-in should do so? Will I need to modify it, or should a plug-in full of vectors work alright?

Comment: In simplified way, make `std::vector<std::vector<int>> pluginDataList;` a **singleton** global and visible from plugins. Each plugin inserts data in your singleton via a call thank to a dummy `static`. (Be careful with *Static Initialization Order Fiasco*).

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah! That's clever, so approach it from the other angle. I know the name of the final list, so that's what I should target. That's a bloody good idea! How can I give you points via comments?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you save the data as JSON between the application and the plugins ? That way you will also allow other types of tech to plug-into your app, like javascript based plugins via an embedded version of v8 or c#/.net plugins via mono.'

Comment: Is JSON going to help me dynamically detect data from a random assortment of plugins at runtime? I don't need an interface with other languages, it'll all be c++